# How to set defaultDate

Tags: javascript, react-native, native-base

How to set defaultDate to 1 month ago from moment date

```
<DatePicker
  defaultDate={}
  minimumDate={new Date()}
  ...
/>
```

I can't imagine what I must to put into defaultDate

Comment: You can see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

refer : https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#date-picker-def-headref

defaultDate - when user opens the date picker the default date will be highlighted

```
let lastMonth =  new Date(); 
lastMonth.setMonth(lastMonth.getMonth() - 1)
```

```
<DatePicker
        defaultDate={lastMonth}
        minimumDate={lastMonth}
        locale={"en"}
        timeZoneOffsetInMinutes={undefined}
        modalTransparent={false}
        animationType={"fade"}
        androidMode={"default"}
        placeHolderText="Select date"
        textStyle={{ color: "green" }}
        placeHolderTextStyle={{ color: "#d3d3d3" }}
        onDateChange={this.setDate}
        disabled={false}
        />
```

Using moment

```
let lastMonth = new Date(moment().subtract(1, 'months').format(moment.defaultFormat))
```

Comment: Yes, I have read this docs. But I want to set to exactly one month ago from momentdate.

Comment: Can you show some part of code? Where is your lastMonth function? Which library I have to use?

Comment: let lastMonth =  new Date(); 
lastMonth.setMonth(lastMonth.getMonth() - 1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use vanilla Javascript's [setMonth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMonth) and [getMonth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) functions.

```
var default_date = new Date();
default_date.setMonth(default_date.getMonth()-1);

<DatePicker
  defaultDate={default_date}
  minimumDate={new Date()}
  ...
/>
```

Comment: can I set up with package 'moment'

Comment: I am not familiar with the package 'moment'. Bu there seems to be another answer posted on this post that uses that package. I'd suggest you try that.

Answer (score 1):

```
let lastMonth = new Date()
lastMonth.setMonth(lastMonth.getMonth() - 1)

<DatePicker
  defaultDate={lastMonth}
  minimumDate={new Date()}
  ...
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

> https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/subtract/

```
    var currentDate = moment('2015-10-30');
    var pastmonth = moment(currentDate).subtract(1, 'M');

    <DatePicker
      defaultDate={pastmonth}
      minimumDate={new Date()}
      ...
    />
```